# how to validate file size while uploading in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, file-upload, drupal-6

I am using file_save_upload() function to upload my files in the Drupal 6 site. I want to limit the maximum file size to 1 MB for uploading.

In summary, "How can I measure the size before passing the file to file_save_upload() function?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [file_validate_size()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_validate_size/6) to check the file's size before calling [file_save_upload()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_save_upload/6)

Here are a few examples of these functions in use:
[Drupal: File upload required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996134/drupal-file-upload-required)
[Create image upload field using Drupal Form API](http://www.akchauhan.com/create-image-upload-field-using-drupal-form-api/)

Comment: I checked that function. file_validate_size() is accepting a drupal file object. Do you know any way that I can pass the file object from $form_state variable?

Comment: @Muneer I have added examples of use in my answer

Comment: This could be a nice solution. THanks for the examples @Laxman13